# Persistent data structures in Rust

Tags: rust, data-structures, persistence, immutability

How to implementing a basic persistent data structure that utilizes structural sharing? The code provided below is functional, but I would like to receive input on whether this approach is suitable for Rust or if there are potentially more efficient alternatives and if Rc is the right container for this?

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d3bb0eec36426c254e374327a5b15201)

```rust
struct Persistent<T> {
    vec: Vec<Rc<T>>,
    var: Rc<T>
} 

impl<T> Persistent<T> {
    pub fn add(&self, item: T) -> Self {
        let mut next_vec = self.vec.clone();
        next_vec.push(Rc::new(item));
        Persistent { 
            vec: next_vec,
            var: self.var.clone() 
        }
    }

    pub fn set_var(&self, item: T) -> Self {
        Persistent {
            vec: self.vec.clone(),
            var: Rc::new(item)
        }
    }
}

#[test]
fn main() {
    let a: Persistent<i32> = Persistent { 
        vec: vec![Rc::new(1), Rc::new(2), Rc::new(3)],
        var: Rc::new(0) 
    };

    let b = a.add(4);
    assert_eq!(3, a.vec.len());
    assert_eq!(4, b.vec.len());
    assert_eq!(Rc::as_ptr(&a.vec[2]), Rc::as_ptr(&b.vec[2]));
}
```

Comment: This question is opinion based and should be closed, unless you can provide an objectively measurable metric of what you're looking for.

Comment: Maybe the [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rust) might be better suited to this question.

Comment: True, I wasn't aware of codereview.stackexchange. What is the best way to move this question over there? Close it and post it again?

Comment: I'm not sure it fits on Code Review either. Anyhow, make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: Tricky, I think the best thing to do is not to cross-post, but to rephrase my question....